# Beginners guide to offline docker & docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Considering “no online internet acess on server” phenomena in enterprises netwoek - how one approach docker & docker registry practice ?

Answer (score 2):

[With a mirror and/or proxy.](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/)

Your private registry has Internet to proxy public images, and everyone uses it as a mirror. Where the registry cannot have Internet, [push your own images](https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-6-docker-private-registry-15d1fd899255) or otherwise stage the content.

This is the same basic problem as mirroring OS updates (yum, apt, WSUS) for networks without Internet. Calling this a "container registry" rather than "package repository" doesn't really change that you mirror HTTP downloads, only the tools you use to do so.